# Track same objects on multiple cameras

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

For an enhanced tracking project, I would like to know:

**How to track the same object on multiple cameras?**

For example, a thief is walking through a shopping mall and is being captured on multiple cameras. Now I want to reconstruct the way the thief has taken through the shopping mall.

Thanks!

Comment: detect objects, then try to recognize known objects. Approaches might strongly depend on your task, for example there are some methods for face-recognition, so recognizing a (previous seen) person might be possible with "standard" code, while you might need to invent your own wheel for recognition of cars over multiple cameras.

Comment: just think about how you would do this as a human. you'd look for a guy wearing the same clothes (colour, patterns), has the same body shape (tall, small fat, thin), hair colour,.. also you might be able to predict where someone will appear in camara 2 when he leaves camera 1 in a certain direction)

Comment: In a specific case (security cameras for shopping mall), should be irrelevant in a general case, what I would do is: multiple cameras with region overlapping between at least two cameras, calibration between the cameras to know the geometric transformation between each cameras. When a person is tracked in one camera, assuming the ground floor equation is known (calibration step), it should be possible to get the position of this person in the image in the others overlapped cameras.